# Glob known subpaths

Tags: glob

I am not sure of the name of this feature, but I want to use a glob to limit a path to two known branches.

```bash
ls /my/path/to/here/
ls /my/path/to/orhere/
```

I vaguely remember the syntax being something like the following;

```bash
ls /my/path/to/[here,orhere]/
```

That syntax doesn't seem to work. The use of `ls` and path is for example only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
ls /my/path/to/{here, orhere}
```

It's called brace expansion: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html